# gcloud functions deploy always says: --region: NAME must be specified

Tags: gcloud

If I do

```
cloud functions deploy --trigger-http --env-vars-file .env.yaml --region=europe-west2
```

.env.yaml :

```
runtime: nodejs10
region: europe-west2
```

I get this error

ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) argument --region: NAME must be specified.

If I try this `➜  cloud git:(master) ✗ gcloud functions deploy --trigger-http --env-vars-file .env.yaml --region=europe-west2`

I still get the same error

running the command in the root folder:

also contains
src/index.js:

```
'use strict';
exports.http = (request, response) => {
    response.status(200).send("Hello World! Let's start Typescript!!");
};
exports.event = (event, callback) => {
    callback();
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing the name of the function.

According to the command [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy):

> NAME
>
> ID of the function or fully qualified identifier for the function. This positional must be specified if any of the other arguments in this group are specified.

Since you're specifying other arguments in that group, you should add the function name.

I'm not sure why the error talks about the region argument, but you can try to add the name and see if it works.

Also, adding `--verbosity debug` on the command will give you clues about what `gcloud` is actually understanding from your command.

Comment: Thanks for the docs, I understood that you don't supply a function name, everything needs to be in the index.js

Comment: Re-reading the error, it's not clear, but it can be interpreted as "You need to provide the `NAME` argument to use the --`region=REGION` flag".

Comment: @jofre is correct. The command needs to be `gcloud functions deploy [[FUNCTION-NAME]] ...`. You may use `--set-env-vars` or `--env-vars-file` to set environment variables that the deployed function may access but not to name the Cloud Function.

Comment: So this worked **gcloud functions deploy helloWorld --runtime nodejs10 --trigger-http --env-vars-file .env.yaml** but this didn't **gcloud functions deploy helloWorld --runtime nodejs10 --trigger-http --project myproj** any ideas why

Comment: As the docs for the `gcloud` command say, you can pass a fully qualified function name to specify the project. It's not clear what that means, but checking [the API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#CloudFunction.FIELDS.name), it looks like it's in the form of `projects/{project_id}/locations/{location_id}/functions/{function_id}`.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the function name, I fixed this issue by adding the function name.
`gcloud functions deploy function_name --trigger-http --env-vars-file .env.yaml --region=europe-west2`